# Why my PHP Curl POST request turns data array into string?

Tags: php, arrays, curl, post, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to send some data to a given API with the POST method.
I wrote a function in order to execute any CURL request from my project.
When I use it with a param which the value is an array, this array is automatically turned into a string "Array".

Exemple : 
Here is my function :

```
function callAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        // First var_dump()
        var_dump($data);

        switch ($method)
        {
            case "POST":
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                if ($data) {
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                    // Second var_dump()
                    var_dump($data);
                }
                break;
            case "PUT":
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
                break;
            default:
                if ($data)
                    $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
        }

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


        $auth = "username:pwd";
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        ....
    }
```

Here is an use case of my function :

```
$values = array(
    "param1" => "value1",
    "param2" => "value2",
    "param3" => "value3",
     ...
    "param10" => array("23"),
);


callAPI('POST', "https://myapi", $values);
```

The first var_dump prints the corrects values :

```
array(4) {
    ["param1"]=>
        string(6) "value1"
    ["param2"]=>
        string(6) "value2"
    ["param3"]=>
        string(6) "value3"
    ["param10"]=>
        array(1) {
            [0]=>
                string(2) "23"
        }
}
```

But the second one gives a wrong value for "param10" :

```
array(4) {
    ["param1"]=>
        string(6) "value1"
    ["param2"]=>
        string(6) "value2"
    ["param3"]=>
        string(6) "value3"
    ["param10"]=>
        string(5) "Array"
}
```

Is there someone having an idea in order to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `http_build_query()` also in POST. You have to replace your `curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);` like this: `curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));`

Comment: I thought a POST request didn't be like "param=value1&param2=value2...". Thanks you very much !

Comment: glad to be helpful :)

Comment: @Bapt it's 2 different formats for uploading the variables. http_build_query will use the `application/x-www-urlencoded` format, and using an array will make curl use the `multipart/form-data` format. they both have their ups and downs. but in both cases, its wrong to send the header `Content-Type: application/json`